# Landscape/portrait images in email

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mjml

I'm writing an email via `Ruby on Rails` and `MJML` framework, and have different images I want to include with it. Currently the images are hosted on S3 and we source them in the HTML. Some of them are **landscape** and some are **portrait**, and thus should be cropped and centered to have the same size.

If I were in a regular web environment I would solve it using regular [css methods](http://blog.matthewcheok.com/a-better-img-tag/) (`background-image` attribute). But I also want the email to be compatible with **Outlook** (at least the last version), which the method I mentioned [isn't compatible with](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Now I'm considering downloading the images and then implementing crop logic using [this gem](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick) and adding them as an **attachment**. But I would glad to know about any other alternative.

Comment: What are the dimensions?

Comment: They come in different sizes but I want to crop only about 150X150 from the center

Comment: I've solved it using the gem I've specefied.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `object-fit` and `object-position` are supported in Outlook. I know **they are not** in IE and Edge.

You can *try* this if it's supported.

right-click on each title and open in new tab to see the actual image

```css
.image-parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-parent>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://i.share.pho.to/18d84aae_o.jpeg">Landscape</a>
<div class="image-parent">
  <img src="http://i.share.pho.to/18d84aae_o.jpeg">
</div>
<a href="http://i.share.pho.to/eb321087_o.jpeg">portrait</a>
<div class="image-parent">
  <img src="http://i.share.pho.to/eb321087_o.jpeg">
</div>
<a href="http://i.share.pho.to/57896478_o.jpeg">square</a>
<div class="image-parent">
  <img src="http://i.share.pho.to/57896478_o.jpeg">
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like the best solution, but those properties aren't compatible as suspected. Email clients are in the state that browsers were about 8 years ago.